# Callback URL is not working in Sample Billing Engine WSo2 AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried integrating sample Billing Engine in WSO2 API Manager. Everything was working fine till Subscription. Redirection to store after signup is not working. I am following the steps from below URL. Please guide me.

By default, impl jasr was pointing to 5.0.4 snapshot. Since it's not available i am referring to 6.0.3.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/

Also, I have installed wso2 in ubuntu and given the jkspath as carbon_home/sercurity/wso2carbon.jks. Is it something wrong?

Comment: What is you APIM version?

Comment: WSo2 API Manager 1.10.0. I am aware that it can be used in 1.9.0 but there are some features which i may need from 1.10.0. So, I would want to integrate the billing module with the same version. It would be very helpful if you could help me on this.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the backend? If yes, plz update the question with them.