# Callback after user register in Billing Engine (WSO2 Api Manager)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have an Active-Active Deployment of WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0, also with WSO2 AM Analytics and WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager (all in high availability).

I have enabled monetization following [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Monetization+of+APIs), deploying *apim-billing-engine-1.3.0.war* in */repository/deployment/server/webapps/*, deploying *subs-workflow-1.3.0.jar* in */repository/component/lib/*, and installing *APIM_Billing_2.2.0.car* in WSO2 AM Analytics.

I turn off one node to test the other node. Everything is as expected, but I have a issue with the Billing Engine. The use case is:

- A) User login in API Store (URL as https://10.90.60.100/store). OK
- B) User subscribes to an commercial API, and it is redirected to the billing engine (URL as
  https://10.90.60.100/apim-billing-engine-1.3.0/app/main?execution=e3s2).
  OK
- C) User fills the new user form, and clicks in "sign up". But it is not redirected to API Store, just stay "Processing..." foverer. In
  logs, it leaves the following error:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-11-27 14:41:54,357] ERROR
>   {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path
>   [/apim-billing-engine-1.3.0] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@3af40bc0 targetAction =
>   [EvaluateAction@761cb83b expression =
>   workflowClient.activateSubscription(redirectBean, user),
>   resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state
>   'signUp' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were
>   'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
>   {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve}
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>   at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>   at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
>   at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
>   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052) at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
>   at
>   org.wso2.apim.billing.services.impl.WorkflowClientImpl.sendPOSTMessage(WorkflowClientImpl.java:104)
>   at
>   org.wso2.apim.billing.services.impl.WorkflowClientImpl.activateSubscription(WorkflowClientImpl.java:87)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:109)
>   at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>   at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>   at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:71)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:195)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:211)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I know it is a cert issue, but I cannot find the exact point.

I have tested the billing engine is getting ok the jks file (datasource.properties file has: *jksPath=/repository/deployment/server/webapps/apim-billing-engine-1.3.0/WEB-INF/classes/wso2-jks/wso2carbon.jks*).

I use the default certificate in wso2store. And I have checked it is in:

- WSO2 API Manager private store:
  /repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
- WSO2 API Manager client-trust store: /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
- Billing machine store: /repository/deployment/server/webapps/apim-billing-engine-1.3.0/WEB-INF/classes/wso2-jks/wso2carbon.jks
- WSO2 AM Analytics private store: /repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
- WSO2 AM Analytics client-trust store: /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
- WSO2 IS as KM private store: /repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
- WSO2 IS as KM client-trust store: /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks

I have added the WSO2 public certificate to Java Certificate Store following [this post](https://nadeesha678.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/adding-wso2-public-certificate-to-java-certificate-store/), with same result.

Some pages ([this](http://evanthika.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-solve-pkix-path-building-failed.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498159/wso2-api-manager-invalid-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested)) say that similar error is shown when a WSO2 product cannot connect to a backend API, because a cert issue. I think this cannot be my problem because in my case, my WSO2 Api Manager dont throw the error trying to connect to a backend API, but trying to connect to billing engine (that uses wso2carbon cert, same as WSO2 Api Manager)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609068/callback-url-is-not-working-in-sample-billing-engine-wso2-am) has the same problem (but he don't leave the log error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this pointing the property jksPath of datasource.properties file of apim-billing-engine-1.3.0 to the *client-truststore.jks* file, instead of *wso2carbon.jks* file.

In the official [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Monetization+of+APIs), jksPath is pointing to the *wso2carbon.jks* file. Also default file and all other examples that I have seen are pointing to the *wso2carbon.jks* file. Maybe this should be changed in the official documentation and default file (github and war).